# Django query with an aggregate function

Tags: python, django

I have following models:

```
class TopicLabel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    order = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def hasTopics():
        return TopicLabelConnection.objects.filter(labelId=self.id).count() > 0

class TopicLabelConnection(models.Model):
    topicId = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name='connection_topic')
    labelId = models.ForeignKey(TopicLabel, related_name='connection_label')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.labelId.name + ' / ' + self.topicId.title
```

In a certain view I want to create a list of all `TopicLabel`s, which have at least one connection (i. e. where `hasTopics` returns `true`).

AFAIK it is impossible in Django to use instance methods in `filter` expressions (i. e. something like `TopicLabel.objects.filter(TopicLabel.hasTopics).order_by('order')` is impossible).

What is the correct (Django-style) way to implement such query (preferably database-independent) ?

Comment: Don't use `count` to examine existence. use `queryset.exists()` insted. It is much easier for your database. `count()` can be harmful.

Comment: Now really an answer to your question but if your TopicLabelConnection model exists purely to connect two other models then you could probably use the Django ManyToMany field and have it generate and manage the tables for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this specific case, you don't need an aggregation function at all.  Use an `isnull` filter:

```
TopicLabel.objects.filter(connection_label__isnull=False)
```

For cases where you do need an aggregate, you can filter on annotations as described in the [aggregation documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations).